# copy files of all directory from specific directory to different location containing same directory names

Tags: linux, cp

I have to cp below files to another dir which contains same dir name.

Dir Structure of abc dir:

```
[ab@ab abc]$ pwd
/home/ab/abc
[ab@ab abc]$ ls
dir1  dir2  README.md
```

I want to cp content in all dir present in /home/4px/abc and not any other files types in abcdir to/home/4px/xyzdir which contains same dir structure of abc dir.

Dir Structure of xyz dir

```
[ab@ab abc]$ pwd
[ab@ab xyz]$ ls
/home/ab/xyz
dir1  dir2
```

If `dir1`, `dir2` already exist in `xyz` dir then update contents in dir.

I am using following command to fulfill the condition.

```
[ab@ab home]$ find /home/ab/abc -type d -name "dir*" -exec cp -r {} /home/ab/xyz \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a source and a destination directory, and I've run following command:

```
Linux Prompt> cd source
Linux Prompt> find . -type d -exec mkdir /c/Temp_Folder/destination/{} \;
```

For your information: the switch `-type d` makes sure only directories are handled, so all files will be skipped.

You'll get a message, saying that `.` directory already exists, but all other directories/subdirectories will be created.

Comment: if `dir1` already exist in `destination` dir, then will it `cp` all latest files inside `dir1`?

Comment: @Divyank: I've edited my answer, mentioning that all files will be skipped, because of `-type d`.